# How to detect when user turns off GPS with FusedLocationProviderClient?

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderclient

Now that FusedLocationProvider API is deprecated, I am using FusedLocationProviderClient, but I couldn't find how to detect when user turns the location off. Is there any listener for this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationCallback

wich expose

```
public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability)
```